# Contar días entre fechas de mis registros

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tratare de explicar lo mejor que se pueda el problema que tengo...

Estoy tratando de contar los días que hay entre fechas en mi base de datos pero siempre y cuando estén dentro del rango (2020-07-28 al 2021-07-28  por ejemplo a partir del id 3 abarca el rango de fecha) y realice una sumatoria del total de los días que entran en el rango de fechas.

al final lo que necesito es que calcule los días entre "entrada" y "salida" pero que estos esten dentro del rango de fechas que mencione anteriormente.

Esta es la consulta que realizo pero no me funciona.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM viaje WHERE destino='USA' AND entrada BETWEEN '2020-07-28' AND '2021-07-28' OR salida BETWEEN '2020-07-28' AND '2021-07-28'
```

```html
             MI BASE DE DATOS

| -------------- TABLA viaje -------------|
| id |   entrada   |   salida   | destino | 
-------------------------------------------
| 10 |  2021-07-20 | 2021-07-28 |   USA   |
|  9 |  2021-07-11 | 2021-07-13 |   USA   |
|  8 |  2021-06-10 | 2021-07-10 |   USA   |
|  7 |  2021-04-05 | 2021-04-10 |   USA   |
|  6 |  2021-01-20 | 2021-01-22 |   USA   |
|  5 |  2020-12-20 | 2021-01-05 |   USA   |
|  4 |  2020-10-11 | 2020-10-30 |   USA   |
|  3 |  2020-06-22 | 2020-07-30 |   USA   |
|  2 |  2020-02-15 | 2020-03-10 |   USA   |
|  1 |  2020-01-01 | 2020-01-10 |   USA   |
```

Comment: Al usar `COUNT(*)` estarías contando las filas que cumplen el criterio, si lo que quieres es la diferencia de días entre dos fechas lo propio es usar [`DATEDIFF()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff), algo así más o menos: `SELECT DATEDIFF(salida, entrada) AS days`

Comment: ¿Cuál es el resultado esperado?

Comment: el resultado esperado es la cantidad de días entre las fechas de entrada y salida siempre y cuando estén los días entre el rango de fechas.. y al final realizar una suma con la cantidad de los días y mostrarla

Comment: ¿Cuál es el motivo de usar un `date` o `string` y no usar un `timestamp`? Con este ultimo con una simple resta resuelves este problema y otros muchos, eso sin contar que convertir esto a una fecha es muy rápido y no necesitas cargar el servidor para ello

Comment: ¿Podrías dar un ejemplo con datos del resultado esperado? es decir, un ejemplo de los componentes de la suma junto con el resultado de la suma total.

Comment: No logro entender del todo la pregunta, como mencionan en los comentarios anteriores, crear un EMCV ([Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) sería de ayuda. Aquí un [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4310ca5b005998609fb1b6cebdb0022d) propuesto según lo que entiendo de la pregunta.